# How do I make pyttsx3 not give me an (libespeak.os not found) error in repl.it

Tags: python, error-handling, pyttsx3

When I run my program in replit.com:

```
import gspread

import pyttsx3

gc = gspread.service_account(filename='credentials.json')

sh = gc.open_by_key('1rdccFZmL3nI8gV2_dfw-fKDGjK3RtQG3D4JqDWAdWIg')

worksheet = sh.worksheet('temp')

cell_value = worksheet.acell('A2').value

engine = pyttsx3.init()

engine.say(f'Hi! The value of cell A2 is {cell_value}.')

engine.runAndWait()
```

I get the error:

```
OSError: libespeak.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried to install and uninstall espeak. I also tried to make a workaround by using Gtts but that did not work and I would prefer to use the module I am using now.